# How can I save an XML DOM tree to a new document using Perl's XML::LibXML?

Tags: xml, perl, dom, libxml2

I write the following (DOM) Perl script (shown below) in order to create the following XML DOM:

```
 <books>
 <computer/>
 </books>
```

How can I save the XML output into `test.xml` file? I tried to save the XML with

```
 $doc->printToFile('/tmp/test.xml');
```

but I get:

`can't locate object method "printToFile" via package "XML::LibXML::Document"`

The Perl script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 use XML::LibXML;
 my $doc;
 $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new;

 my $objbooks = $doc->createElement('books');
 $doc->appendChild($objbooks);

 my $objcomputer = $doc->createElement('computer');
 $objbooks->appendChild($objcomputer);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want [`XML::LibXML::Document::toFile`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::LibXML::Document#toFile):

> ```
>  $state = $doc->toFile($filename, $format);
> ```
>
> This function is similar to `toString()`, but it writes the document directly into a filesystem. This function is very useful, if one needs to store large documents.
>
> The format parameter has the same behaviour as in `toString()`.

Comment: hi again , I add the $doc->toFile('/tmp/test.xml'); , after that , test.xml was created but without the element lines as <books> <computer> .... ?? why